# C - I am calculating amortization and my results are off

Tags: c, amortization

I am trying to calculate the monthly payment of a loan and it always comes out wrong.

The formula is as follows where i is interest

```
((1 + i)^months /
(1 + i)^months - 1)
* principal * i
```

Assuming that annual interest rate and principal is an invisible floating point, can you tell me what's wrong with my formula?

```
double calculatePaymentAmount(int annualInterestRate, 
     int loanSize,                          
     int numberOfPayments;
{
double monthlyInterest = annualInterestRate / 1200.0;
return 
    (
        pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) /
        (pow(1 + monthlyInterest, numberOfPayments) - 1)
    )
    * (loanSize / 100)
    * monthlyInterest;
}
```

For example: an interest rate of 1.25 and a loan size of 250 for 12 months gives 22.27 instead of 20.97.

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: Changed monthly interest to annualInterestRate / 1200

Comment: Just a tip also: Put a trailing `.0` to constants when you want floating point just to make sure the result is floating point too.

Answer (score 0):

converting

```
double monthlyInterest = (double)annualInterestRate / 
    1200 / 100;
```

to

```
double monthlyInterest = (double)annualInterestRate / 12.0;
```

would do the trick.

you may read more about operator precedence in c from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I use invisible floating point so I store say 1.25 as 125 and change that back by dividing annualInterestRate by 1200 to get monthly interest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `annualInterestRate` is in percent, then you should calculate `monthlyInterest` like this:

```
double monthlyInterest = pow(1+(double)annualInterestRate / 100, 1/12.0) - 1.0;
```

Comment: Where would that change the formula?

Comment: @user1892641 125.0 / 1200.0 / 100.0 = 0.0010416...; pow( 1.0125, 1/12.0) - 1.0 = 0.0010357...

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. monthlyInterest = annualInterestRate / 1200.0 / 100